# What is my "fell might"?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

I'm looking at the Scornful Denial feat and it tells me that "when you regain your **fell might**, you can make a saving throw against an effect that a save can end."

What *is* my fell might? The wiki I usually look through uses the phrase but never explains it.

Answer (score 10):

#### Fell Might is an expendable feature of the Fell Scorn pact boon, from the Sorcerer King Warlock pact.

When you choose the Sorcerer King pact, you gain the Fell Scorn pact boon, which states:

> Fell Scorn: You have the Fell Scorn pact boon,
> which enables you to draw upon your sorcerer-king’s
> magical prowess and enhance a power by spending
> your fell might. You start each encounter with your
> fell might unspent. You must decide whether or not
> to spend your fell might when you choose to use a
> power, before you make any attack rolls or apply any
> of that power’s effects.
>
> When a creature affected by your Warlock’s
> Curse drops to 0 hit points, your pact boon triggers,
> restoring your fell might, which you can spend again
> during the encounter. If you already have your fell
> might available when a cursed creature drops to 0 hit
> points, you don’t gain a second use of it. You can have
> only one use of fell might available at one time.
>
> -*Dark Sun Campaign Setting*, pg. 94

Since Scornful Denial has Sorcerer King as one of its prerequisites, this feature is naturally what Scornful Denial is referring to: when you regain your use of Fell Might as described in the Fell Scorn pact boon feature, you may use Scornful Denial to make a saving throw against an effect that a save can end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is strange, though. My Warlock has Dark Pact, yet, it is a suggested feat.

Comment: @Bear Now that is odd, I’ll have to look into it more later.